# Not seeing speed up with Python Async IO

Tags: python, python-asyncio, nest-asyncio

I have an IO operation (POST request for each Pandas row) which I'm trying to speed up using Async IO. An alternative minimal example can be found below. I want to understand why the 1st sample doesn't run in parallel and 2nd sample is faster.

1st Sample:

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


async def add(x: int, y: int, delay: int):
  sleep(delay) #await asyncio.sleep(delay)
  return x+y
  

async def get_results():
  inputs = [(2,3,9), (4,5,7), (6,7,5), (8,9,3)]
  
  cors = [add(x,y,z) for x,y,z in inputs]
  results = asyncio.gather(*cors)
    
  print(await results)

asyncio.run(get_results())

# This takes ~24s
```

2nd Sample:

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


async def add(x: int, y: int, delay: int):
  await asyncio.sleep(delay)
  return x+y
  

async def get_results():
  inputs = [(2,3,9), (4,5,7), (6,7,5), (8,9,3)]
  
  cors = [add(x,y,z) for x,y,z in inputs]
  results = asyncio.gather(*cors)
    
  print(await results)

asyncio.run(get_results())

# This takes ~9s as expected
```

In my case the `sleep` can be replace with `requests.post()`

Comment: Not that just like time.sleep is not async, neither is requests. If you want to use asyncio, you’ll need to use a library like aiohttp instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` isn't async aware, so trying to use it in an `async` function doesn't make anything faster.

You will need an async aware HTTP library such as `httpx` or `aiohttp` to make HTTP requests that don't block `async` functions.

Similarly, in the first example, you're using a non-async-aware function, `time.sleep`, which blocks the async loop.

Also, a non-IO, Python-native-code operation (an addition) will not be sped up by `asyncio`.

(Recall that `async` doesn't mean that the functions would be run in parallel, quite the contrary.)

Comment: Makes sense. I tried multi-process and it does speedup requests.

Comment: It's also an entirely different thing with an entirely different set of tradeoffs. You will have a bad time performance-wise if you try to move a lot of data in and out of multiprocessing children.

Comment: What is recommended for sending payload row-by-row from a pandas dataframe?

Comment: There's no single recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `time.sleep` is not async. Thread will be blocking and waiting when running to the code `time.sleep`.

However `await asyncio.sleep` is async. Thread will be free to execute other code when running to the code `await asyncio.sleep`.

`sync` just like you must order a food and waiting it completion. Then you can oder next food.

`async` means you can order all food in a time and waiting them completion.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your code hits sleep.delay it will block all other co-routines from executing in the event loop. All function have to be async compatible